# how to find the first negative term in an AP

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

If $a$ is the first term and $-d$ is common difference then $n^{\textrm{th}}$ term is $a+(n-1)(-d)$.

Now if in this AP if we are asked what will be the first negative term then how does $a+(n-1)(-d)<0$ give the answer?

I mean why is it giving the first negative term why not any other negative term?

Comment: Arithmetic progressions are monotonic, meaning they are either always increasing or always decreasing. Your common difference is negative, so this sequence is always decreasing. Solving for $n$ in your inequality will give an inequality bound on $n$ where all $n$ satisfying that will give negative terms. Then the smallest $n$ satisfying that inequality should give the first negative term.

Comment: Is there any reason why we are getting the smallest value of 'n'?

Comment: Solving this sort of linear inequality always produces a solution set which is a half-line $(c,\infty)$. Every integer larger than $c$ is in the solution set, and there is a smallest integer in the set (the first integer to the right of $c$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't give the first negative term. It gives *all* values of $n$ which produce negative terms. If you continue, you have

$$a + (n-1)(-d)< 0$$
$$(n-1)(-d)< -a$$
$$n-1 > \frac{-a}{-d}=\frac ad\tag{assuming $d>0$, so $-d<0$}$$
$$n > 1 + \frac ad$$
Every positive integer greater than $1+\frac ad$ will produce a negative term. The *first* such integer will produce the *first* negative term, and all terms thereafter will also be negative.

For example, if $a=1$ and $d=2$, then you get $n>1+1/2=1.5$, so the positive integers satisfying $n>1.5$ are $2,3,4,5,\cdots$ and the first of these is $2$; so the second term is the first negative term.

You can verify this by observing that the corresponding progression is
$$1, \underbrace{-1}_{2^{\textrm{nd}}\textrm{ term}}, -3, -5, -7, \ldots$$

Comment: oh i got it thanks man :)